# Ubuntu Server 16.04 SW RAID1 LVM - broken RAID unable to boot

Tags: boot, raid, lvm

I have an old notebook hp nx9020. I want to use RAID1 so I have PCMCIA card - SATA controller and SATA drive on it. I am using this configuration for years (maybe 8 years) on Debian, later on Ubuntu server and there was no problem. I have upgraded Ubuntu server from 14.04 to 16.04 and I was unable to boot. I tried to reinstall system three times but still the same problem, system is unable to boot, it can not find volume group (LVM). SATA controller driver is loaded after boot, I was always running this system with one internal IDE drive and I created RAID array after boot.

I tried to do the same on virtualbox VM. I installed ubuntu server 16.04 i386 with forcepae option on two virtual drives. I have created RAID1 for /boot (ext4), LVM with /(ext4) on another RAID1 and swap on third RAID1 array. System booted successfully. I removed one virtual drive and system is unable to boot.

error screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

final state:
[image: final state]

Can you help me please? Thank you

Update:
I made some comparison between booting with one and two drives

booting with one drive:
[image: booting with one drive]

booting with two drives:
[image: booting with two drives]